# Custom converters not passing list

Tags: python, flask, redirect, url-routing

What I wish to do is to send data which is a list to another function via inbuilt flask function render and url_for using a custom converter made using werkzeug.routing base converter.
backend.py:

```
from flask import *
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL
from werkzeug.routing import BaseConverter
mysql = MySQL()
application = Flask(__name__)
class ListConverter(BaseConverter):
    def to_python(self, value):
        return value.split('+')

   def to_url(self, values):
        return '+'.join(BaseConverter.to_url(value)
                        for value in values)

application.url_map.converters['list'] = ListConverter
@application.route('/reportsscr',methods=["POST"])
def reportsscr():
        results = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
        return redirect(url_for('reportsview',value =results))
```

And calling it in another file which is
Main.py

```
from backend import *
@application.route('/view/<list:value>')
def reportsview(value):
    return str(value)
```

This is the snapshot of error I am getting:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHYks.png)

Answer (score 0):

I found some [examples](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/102944/werkzeug.routing.BaseConverter) of how to do this through google searches.  I think you may need to tweak your to_url function.

```
class ListConverter(BaseConverter):
    def to_python(self, value):
        return value.split('+')

   def to_url(self, value):
#change values to value, get super to_url function
        base_to_url = super(ListConverter, self).to_url
        return '+'.join(base_to_url(x)
                        for x in value)
```

Comment: throws an error 404 not found and I am unable to debug it.

Comment: Can you try just changing the parameter to_url takes to "value" instead of values and adjusting your function accordingly?